# Does the video for Last In Line match the intent of the Lyrics?

Tags: lyrics

Do the scenes depicted in the music video for The Last in Line (Dio, 1984) relate directly to the meaning of the lyrics as intended by the original artist?

Both contain Biblical imagery, but while the lyrics contain references to both the old and new testaments, including various prophesies and end time theological references, the music video appears to be an indirect reference to Joachim of Fiore, or at least later derivatives\interpretations of it and are a possible reference to the panic over rock\metal music in the 1980s.

Has anything authoritative ever been written on the subject, for example, has Dio ever spoken directly about it to the media?